# Using preg_match_all() to locate XML within a log in PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex, epp

I have several log files that contain EPP requests and responses. I need to use preg_match_all to return an array of all the XML requests within the log, so I can then parse out the XML and validate it, however I'm not too familiar with regex. The XML should always begin with...

```
<?xml
```

...and end with...

```
</epp>
```

How would I form Regex to find everything contained between and including these identifiers.

Comment: I'm really a novice at the whole regex thing, but I did try a few amalgamations of the following code... No luck.

    <?php
    $string = file_get_contents("epp_log2.txt");
    preg_match_all("/\<\?xml/./\<\/epp>/", $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `s` flag in which `.` matches new lines as well, and a whole capture group:

```
preg_match_all("/(<\?xml.*?<\/epp>)/s", $content, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Why a capturing group?